# Map navigation plugin for jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

i searched for hours for this plugin with no result as the keywords map, image and navigation are used in many different plugins.

A more precise therm would be helpful as well.

I'm looking for a plugin that allows me to navigate on an image, like google maps does, with drag and drop and mouse scroll for zoom in/out.

Ajax load of parts of the map would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/ (though it's not a jquery plugin), or http://homepage.mac.com/bendik/imagetool/demo/index.html.

The keywords you are looking for are PAN and IMAGE ZOOM.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You can try jmaps, which is a google maps plugin for jquery:

http://github.com/digitalspaghetti/jmaps/

http://code.google.com/p/jmaps/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jmaps

Or maybe some of these other map plugins for jquery listed under the jquery page:

http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/841

This link lists some other jQuery plugins that take advantage of google maps api and some of the other google APIs

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/8-jquery-plugins-that-utilize-google-apis/

Comment: One up from me cause your reply is waayyy better.

Comment: @aefxx Thanks. Your reply is actually what the OP was looking for though. That shiftzoom plugin looks pretty cool.